# search and replace preword from author

Tags: php, javascript, html

On the post page I display the author of the article. But I have two types of authors.

I have at the one hand " the xxx Team" and on the other "from xxx" but my problem is the pre word.

Now it displays "the xxx team" and "the xxx". This is the part from the code:

```
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID'), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>" class="m-article-author">
                        <?php
                        $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'tierisch_wohnen_author_bio_avatar_size', 49 );
                        echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_bio_avatar_size );
                        ?>

                        The <span class="m-article-author-name"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    </a>
```

I hope someone can help me with a if else function or some search and replace. If anyone have an idea please let me know.

Comment: btw the xxx team is every time the same author

Comment: So you only want to display “the” if the authors name contains the word “team”? Is that right? If not the  it’s not clear from your question what you actually want.

Comment: I need to display "the" if the author is "team" and else the word "from"

Comment: i need help with the condition for the if else  (if the author is team)

Answer (score 0):

This code is my answer:

```
                    <a href="<?php echo get_author_posts_url( get_the_author_meta('ID'), get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename' ) ); ?>" class="m-article-author">
                        <?php
                        $author_bio_avatar_size = apply_filters( 'tierisch_wohnen_author_bio_avatar_size', 49 );
                        echo get_avatar( get_the_author_meta( 'user_email' ), $author_bio_avatar_size );
                        ?>


                    <?php 
                    
                    if (get_the_author_meta('display_name') === 'xxx Team') {
                        echo"The";
                    }
                    else {
                        echo"From";
                    }
                    ?>

                    
                    <span class="m-article-author-name"><?php the_author(); ?></span>
                    </a>
```